# What are the important information that a question tags should contain?

Tags: discussion, tags, faq-proposed

It's often a bit difficult to know what tag to use in a question, especially on a site like IPS.

So, what are the important information, in questions related to interpersonal interaction, that should be shown in tags?

Comment: Related from the MSE faq: [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/232439) and [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31776/232439)

Answer (score -1):

When writing/editing a question, here is what I consider to be the relevant information that should be in the tags:

1. First, the **what**: what do the OP wants to communicate? What are they trying to say? The answer can be "saying-no", "boundaries", "apologies" etc...

   In the what, I'm also looking for the **in what way**: do OP wants to be polite? Avoid conflict?

---

2. Second, the **who**: who is OP trying to communicate with? Is it friends? Family? Stranger?

---

3. Third (and if it's important), the **where**: where is this communication happening? Online? In public transportation? In a specific country?

   In this where, I'm looking for everything that makes the setting special. Like, if this occurs during a long-time conflict, or if there is money, religion or gender involved. Anything that complexifies the situation and makes it more difficult to answer.